# Facebook login localhost oauth

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, oauth, redirect

Right now im working on a Meteor App demo wich let you connect with facebook, im doing it pretty basic and everything is seems to be working nice, but for some reason im having problem with the redirect url.

This is my setup.

BTW im following [login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js](http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/)

The app is on test mode, the `localhost` domain is added and the url is `http://localhost:3000/`, but now, the problem beggins on the redirect url.

If i put `http://localhost:3000/` redirect URL the app works fine and i get the user typing Meteor.user(); on the console.

**BUT**

if i put `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close` i got the

> error 191 invalid redirect url

I dont really know what is happening, im doing something wrong over here? i dont want to keep like this, because i do a little bit of research and having a wrong URL could be a security problem

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close=true`
It might be doing some url parsing, and I don't think ?close without any value is valid